# Setting up a Python development environment on Windows

Tags: python, windows, development-environment

Yes, I've searched. So after spending about 4-5 hours struggling just to get Python files running, I recently stumbled over the solution to get it running through the environment variables like this: cmd -> python -> Python starts, yay yay

Since it didn't work to do it through the command line and similar I had to do it manually through the Windows interface. Now that it's working, however I cannot open .py files without typing out the full path like this: python C:\X\X\X\test.py which is obviously also starting to get annoying.

So now I'm trying to find out which variable I have to change (yet again) to only be able to type 'python test.py' and have it running. Sorry if I come off vague, but it's always a major pain to setup a new programming language for me and it kills my mood.

Thanks for help, it'll be really appreciated.

Comment: Just so we know where you're starting from: Are you familiar with the PATH environment variable?

Comment: I had to manually add ;C:\X\Python2.7 to the PATH, so yes.

Comment: How did you install Python on your machine?  Which Python version did you install?

Comment: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/24/python-101-setting-up-python-on-windows/

Answer (score 2):

When you say

> able to type 'python test.py'

I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Normally when the Python interpreter runs, it looks in the *current directory* for any source file that is named on the command line (unless you specifically name a location for the source file, as you've discovered). It seems from your previous statement:

> python C:\X\X\X\test.py which is obviously also starting to get annoying

that your `test.py` file exists somewhere else.

What you might want to try is to change the current directory first, before running your script. In a command prompt window, type:

```
C:
cd \X\X\X
python test.py
```

(obviously substituting your actual path name). My apologies if you already know this.

Comment: My .py files are in the same directory as my python.exe. That's at least how I understood I needed to have it to make it less complicated in the first place.

Comment: Well, it's certainly not necessary to place `.py` files in the same directory as `python.exe`. On my system, Python is in `c:\python27\python.exe` and I *never* put scripts in that directory. They're always somewhere else, and by virtue of the PATH environment variable containing `c:\python27`, I can run the Python interpreter from anywhere (naturally, I usually run it from the directory where my `.py` files are).

Answer (score 2):

To make `python` executable on your command line, you need to add it to your `PATH` environment variable, which it sounds like you have done on the command line. It is quite simple to add directories to the `PATH` in Windows if you know where to look. Essentially, you need to get to the `Environment Variables` dialog box, which is slightly different for each version of Windows.

> For **Windows XP**: `Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables`
>
> For **Windows Vista, 7**: Click the Start Orb, right-click `Computer` and select `Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables`

Then, in the lower of the two boxes, find `Path` and click `Edit`. Change it so that `C:\Python27` (or whichever version of Python you have) is at one end of the list, separated from the other entries by a semicolon (e.g. `C:\Python27;C:\Program Files ...`)

Once you've done this, `python` will work at the command line whenever you open a command window.

Regarding your second issue, however, there isn't much you can do. You must either specify the complete path to your script or already be in the same directory as the script. That is, if the script is in `C:\X\X\X` you will either need to invoke it as `C:\X\X\X\test.py` or first `cd C:\X\X\X`.

Comment: I just don't understand why "everyone else" can simply type 'python filenamehere.py' and that runs the .py file for them.

Comment: @Peter On Windows, it doesn't just work that way "out of the box" --for Python and other systems like it, you usually need to add its installation directory to your path. On Linux, the python executable is normally installed to a standard directory that is already on most users' path, eliminating the extra step in most cases.

Comment: The Python installer gives you an option to automatically add the Python installation directory to the PATH. So I would say it *does* work "out of the box", unless you tell it not to.